# Adding Request Headers to a manually instantiated ServiceStack object?

Tags: servicestack

```
using(var service = new PlacementService())
{
     service.Request.Headers.Add("Impersonated", "1"); //NULL Exception thrown
}
```

I need to be able to set a header on a manually instantiated ServiceStack class, but the request object is NULL so it's not working. It's being called inside a HttpPost Mvc Controller method.

The service was created to check a header to see if the request was coming from an impersonated user, it's just usually called directly from the frontend, I need to access a couple methods from it in backend code... this is the only thing tripping me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke Services with the [Service Gateway](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway) or by using [ResolveService](https://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-integration#integrating-with-servicestack-from-mvc-or-webforms) from the `ServiceStackController` base class, e.g:

```cs
using var service = ResolveService<PlacementService>();
```

But the `HttpRequestBase.Headers` collection is immutable where you wouldn't be able to modify the HTTP Request collections. Instead you would typically populate the `Items` dictionary to pass additional info to the Service.

Otherwise you could populate the service with a custom `IRequest` which will let you construct your own Request context, e.g:

```cs
using var service = new PlacementService { 
   Request = new BasicRequest(requestDto)
}
```